# How can i access a js file in my project?

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0, file-io, filestream

I want to read "script1.js" by filestream in my console application like below.
But it returns to me an error. Is there any better way to read a js file in application, by using filestream it returns to me error: FileNotFound exception.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing "script1.js" in your code with "~/script1.js". The tilde ("~") means the root of your application.

Comment: Stupid question, but what are you going to do with the contents, once it's loaded?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the debug folder you are showing in the first screenshot. Also, Use code snippets rather than images.

Comment: @MrLister; first of all you have to understand my question. My question is related to loading not interest of content. ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `FileReader` is reading from your build destination not your project destination, it will not find the file (Look at that path it tires to read from, it is `.\bin\Debug\script1.js`, where your file will be at `.\script1.js`)

The easiest fix is to change build action for your script file in its properties, and set `Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the js file's "Generate Operation" property as "Resource" in your project, it will be copy to bin/Debug folder. Or you can copy it to the folder where the exe file is.

Comment: No, not Resource. Resource will integrate it into the EXE file. He must select "Content" and "Copy always".

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "script1.js" is NOT copied to the directory "Debug".

As one solution, you could mark the script1.js in Visual Studio, then go to "Properties" and then set these:

- for "Build Action", choose "Content"
- for "Copy to Output Directory", choose "Copy always"